# hostname in certificate didn't match: <eu1.sms.sdi.sinch.com> != <*.venice.api.sinch.com>

Tags: java, websphere

When I use this I get a 200 -ok

```
SSLConnectionSocketFactory sslSocketFactory = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(
                 SSLContext.getDefault(), 
                 new String[]{T_SAP_CRYPTO_PROTOCOL},
                 (String[])null,
                 SSLConnectionSocketFactory.ALLOW_ALL_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER);
```

but when I use

```
SSLConnectionSocketFactory.STRICT_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER
```

I get:

```
 hostname in certificate didn't match: <eu1.sms.sdi.sinch.com> != <*.venice.api.sinch.com>
```

I have put the cert --sms.sdi.sinch.com-- into cacerts but I don't understand why the error

thanks to all

Answer (score 0):

Issue here you might using url eu1.sms.sdi.sinch.com for outbound ssl connnection but your server using certificate has subject *.venice.api.sinch.com and it not matching. You need to make sure hostname in certificate match with url..

Example url should contains eu1.venice.api.sinch.com which match with hostname in certificate *.venice.api.sinch.com

Comment: thanks for the answer

I have in the jvm args -> jsse.enableSNIExtension=false
is it a possible error/conflict?